# HERE API demo vs actual

Tags: here-api

Our exact same endpoint demo query request using Freemium plan is different than the HERE API demo api endpoint results. As you can see, we do not have `Address` or `contacts`. I'm not sure why the results vary on same exact query and endpoint. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Going through for now a few days, the 400 page dev doc PDF, every word of the online docs, we are seeing a lot of conflicts and as I am sure you know quite a few depreciated endpoints that are then used as examples. But all signs point to the fact that we should be getting this info. The address class is under 'base attributes' under a sub 'location' header, but before the 'extended attributes' starts, which is confusing and might want to be clarified. The contacts and address both show in the depreciated HERE endpoint, however we are using the three CORE endpoints. Explore, Browse & search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have expanded the initial search/explore response based for the Demo App ID in order to enable users do some testing, but it is not turned on for the Freemium App ID. If you need specific details (like address and contact) then you can use places/lookup api like shown below (you search with source: sharing, id: id for the place you can get this from your above query).

We do this because we expect the end-user to select an item to get additional information. When selected, we receive that request, and it is a signal to us that the result is relevant and important to the query.

```
https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/124aabd1-0aef738f80350f8bebb5ed7539bd19a8;context=Zmxvdy1pZD1lNjIyNjczZS0xNDRmLTViMzctYjY3Mi1hNWQ5MmRkNWU4NzRfMTU0MTc4NDk3MzYzOV8wXzU1NDcmc2l6ZT01JlgtRldELUFQUC1JRD1LTnZIaDlhZ0E2WGxKbElDRWhOZiZYLU5MUC1UZXN0aW5nPTE?app_id=xxx&app_code=xxx
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. This is a hard assumption to make not putting an address in a list view of a business listing product in search results. On almost any list view (Yelp, FSQR, etc) the address is a necessity for the users' determination of what listing they want to expand (more than simply a name). We know vicinity is available but this is not structured data. Contacts arguably the same (at least phone/website). 

This took 2 devs very substantial time trying to solve. Reviewed every piece of the enormous HERE docs. Beg you to consider a change & possibly update (& explorer warning)

Comment: This is more of a design that we don't want to overload the information. Still you can contact our sales team to get this enabled for your app id and code like in demo id.

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance Here ;)

Comment: We emailed sales and we were fwd'd to Onix who also then emailed sales and was responded with an email we're not quite sure what to do with. It says the "The reported has accepted the answer given by developer support , please elaborate what has not been answered. " So still trying to get the address and contacts turned on for our app ID. Would you kindly help us directly? We're in an infinite loop it seems and it's been a CPL weeks. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the email id you tried contacting and got the response from.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay must have missed this notification. It is set up on HERE side for our acct. Thank you kindly.